# How to enable network adapter for Windows 8 in VMWare Player

Tags: networking, drivers, windows-8-preview, vmware-player

Just downloaded and installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview onto a VMWare virtual machine. Despite VMWare not recognising the OS (I selected Other -> Other at setup) everything works fine. However, Windows 8 does not recognise the network adapter (I guess it comes without drivers).

Tried changing from NAT to bridged, no luck.

How could I workaround this? Would reinstalling as Windows 7 enable more VMWare driver support? Or should I install a Windows 7 driver in Windows?

UPDATE: The virtual machine won't start anymore. Worked well during install, though.

UPDATE: Changed VM OS type to Windows 7, now I can start again.

UPDATE: Tryed to install VMTools for windows, hanged windows 8, restarted, now it hangs before reaching the logon screen.